# Call Runtime.getRuntime.exec(commands) twice on the same Process object

Tags: java, multithreading, process, centos

I have two different commands (on an external EXE file) represented by two String array `command1` and `command2`. I want to run those two sequentially within the same thread. To be specific, the first command is executed for 10 minutes. If it takes longer time, terminate it and run the second command.  Here is what I am doing.

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    private Process proc;
    private String[] command1;
    private String[] command2;

    public MyRunnable (String[] command1, String[] command2) {
        this.command1 = command1;
        this.command2 = command2;    
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command1);

            StreamGobbler errorGobbler = new StreamGobbler(proc.getErrorStream(), "ERROR");
            StreamGobbler outputGobbler = new StreamGobbler(proc.getInputStream(), "OUTPUT");

            errorGobbler.start();
            outputGobbler.start();

            exitCode = proc.waitFor(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
            if (exitCode)
                System.out.println("Model " + modelPath + ": SUCCESSFULLY!");
            else {
                System.out.println("Model " + modelPath + ": TIMED OUT!");
                proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command2);

                StreamGobbler errorGobbler1 = new StreamGobbler(proc.getErrorStream(), "ERROR");
                StreamGobbler outputGobbler1 = new StreamGobbler(proc.getInputStream(), "OUTPUT");

                errorGobbler1.start();
                outputGobbler1.start();

                proc.waitFor(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
            }             
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            proc.destroy();
        }
    }
}
```

The `StreamGobbler` class I implemented exactly the same as here [www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) to avoid deadlocks. Generally, its role is to let another thread handle the output and error streams of the `proc` object.

I am not sure whether it is appropriate to assign two different sub-processes to the same Process object as above. I observe that the process with command1 still runs even after calling the `proc.waitFor(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)`, which creates a lot of processes on my computer after a while. How to terminate the process of the first command ? I am using Java 1.8 on CentOS 7.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where should I put it ? I tried to put it right after the proc.waitFor(10, TimeUnit.MINUTE) but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `if` if you reach the `else` statement the process has exceeded the timeout, so before you assign the new process to `proc` you must first terminate the previous one. There are two methods for that `proc.destroy()` and `proc.destroyForcibly()`add any of the in you `else` statement before  proc = `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command2);` and it should be fine.